# jQuery UI revert events

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable, revert

I'm looking for a way to revert an element to its original size and position as soon as it leaves a certain droppable.

Essentially, what I have is selection of images that you can drag into a droppable area and resize, but I want to be able "put back" the images in their original locations by moving them off the droppable area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

that's possible if you make the following:

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
out: function(event, ui) {
$(ui.draggable).draggable({ revert: true });
var revert = $(ui.draggable).draggable( "option", "revert" );
$(ui.draggable).draggable( "option", "revert", true );
alert('out: '+$(ui.draggable).position().left);
}
});
```

The bad news is that after the second movement, the block is moved somewhere else not to it original possition. I'm just asked about possible solutions on this page.

[Trouble with dragged revert at multiple block movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797724/trouble-with-dragged-revert-at-multiple-block-movement)