# Trouble with dragged revert at multiple block movement

Tags: jquery, draggable, revert

At the following link : http://probl.frizi.net/ i'm trying to set variable size and position blocks. The colored blocks need to stay within the gray big block. Anyhow I'm trying to keep the colored blocks inside, they tend (at second movement) to deform or to go on a different possition as they started. Revert method is not working as it should or I didn't implemented it correctly.

Till far, I'm trying to do the following (please rightclick and see the Jquery source on the page):

```
var item;
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
out: function(event, ui) { 
    $(item).draggable({ revert: true });
    var revert = $(item).draggable( "option", "revert" );
    $(item).draggable( "option", "revert", true );
    }
}); 

$(".blk").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) { 
    item = $(this);
}
});
```

Comment: Please have a look at the source code at http://probl.frizi.net/ or move one of the colored boxes outside the panel. At the first movement, the left and top position are OK, afte the second movement due a spooky reason the blocks are moved somwhere else. I could assume that the next (wrong) position is relative to the distance you move the block outside the panel. Any help would be really appreciated, I've try to work with snap and other things. Thank you in advance!